# c calls lua function, the return value is on the stack.Need I pop it?

Tags: lua

1. a lua function return two number
2. c++ calls the lua function: foo
3. I don't know whether it's needful to pop the return value of function foo(*lua_pop(L,2);*).
4. please tell me how to do it and why. thanks very much.

part code like this:

```
// lua function
function foo(a, b)
    return a+b, a-b;
end

// c++

lua_getglobal(L,"foo"); // push function
lua_pushnumber(L,1);    // push argument 1
lua_pushnumber(L,2);    // push argument 2

error=lua_pcall(L, 2, 2, 0);

if (!error) {
    printf("return:%s\n",lua_tostring(L,-1));
    printf("return:%s\n",lua_tostring(L,-2));
    // is this needful
    lua_pop(L,2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always try and keep the stack in a known state, in case you call more functions using the same lua_State. If you leave results sitting on the stack and make more calls, you will eventually fill the available stack space up.

So yes, you should pop the 2 results off the stack after using their values.

Comment: Indeed. If you are lazy, lua_pop (l, lua_gettop(l)) will pop all remaining entries off the stack.

Comment: `lua_settop(L, 0)` seems more idiomatic to clear the stack